# canvas updating slows down (probably needs to free some objects)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, canvas, tkinter

This game slows down after about 10 iterations to a crawl. I'm pretty sure that this is due to garbage objects (probably the rectangulars I create at each iteration) that lie there and occupy space even they are not needed. How can I identify the unwanted objects and remove them?

```
# Game of life
from random import randint
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
from enum import Enum
import tkinter as tk


class State(Enum):
    Dead    = 0
    Alive   = 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


class Cell:    
    def __init__(self, m, n, state):
        self.m = np.uint(m)
        self.n = np.uint(n)
        self.state = state

    def kill(self):
        self.state = State.Dead

    def birth(self):
        self.state = State.Alive

    def __str__(self):
        return '({},{}) {}'.format(self.m, self.n, self.state)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({},{}) {}'.format(self.m, self.n, self.state)


class Game:
    def __init__(self, m, n, alive_cells = None):
        self.m = m
        self.n = n
        self.grid = np.ndarray((m,n), dtype = np.uint8)

        if alive_cells:
            self.cells = [Cell(i // n,i % n, State.Alive if (i // n,i % n) in alive_cells else State.Dead) for i in range(m*n)]
        else:
            self.cells = [Cell(i / n,i % n,randint(0,1)) for i in range(m*n)]

        # GUI #
        self.top = tk.Tk()
        self.cell_size = 10000 // 400 #(self.m * self.n)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.top, bg="gray", height=self.m *self. cell_size, width=self.n * self.cell_size)  

    def populate_grid(self):
        for cell in self.cells:
            self.grid[cell.m,cell.n] = cell.state.value

    def show(self, show_GUI = True, print_2_console = False):
        self.populate_grid()

        if print_2_console:
            print('#'*self.m*3)
            print(self.grid)
        if show_GUI:
            self.draw_canvas()

    def iterate(self):
        '''
        Rules:
        (1) If cell has less than 2 neighbours, it dies
        (2) If cell has more than 3 neighbours, it dies
        (3) If cell has 2-3 neighbours, it survives
        (4) If cell has 3 neighbours, it rebirths
        '''
        new_cells = []
        for cell in self.cells:
            alive_neighbours = 0
            for i in range(cell.m - 1, cell.m + 2):
                for j in range(cell.n - 1, cell.n + 2):
                    if i == cell.m and j == cell.n:
                        continue
                    else:
                        try:
                            alive_neighbours += self.grid[i,j]
                        except IndexError:
                            pass


            tmp = deepcopy(cell)

            if alive_neighbours < 2 or alive_neighbours > 3:
                tmp.kill()
            elif alive_neighbours == 3:
                tmp.birth()
            else: # == 2
                pass 

            new_cells.append(tmp)

        self.cells = new_cells
        self.show()

    def draw_canvas(self):    
        for cell in self.cells:
            if cell.state == State.Alive:
                color = 'blue'
            else:
                color = 'red'

            self.canvas.create_rectangle(cell.n*self.cell_size, cell.m*self.cell_size, (1+cell.n)*self.cell_size, (1+cell.m)*self.cell_size, fill=color)

        self.canvas.pack()
        self.update_canvas()
        self.top.mainloop()

    def update_canvas(self): 
        for cell in self.cells:
            if cell.state == State.Alive:
                color = 'blue'
            else:
                color = 'red'

            self.canvas.create_rectangle(cell.n*self.cell_size, cell.m*self.cell_size, (1+cell.n)*self.cell_size, (1+cell.m)*self.cell_size, fill=color)

        # call again after 100 ms
        self.top.after(100, self.iterate)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    glider = (20, 20, ((1,3), (2,3), (2,1), (3,2), (3,3)))
    small_exploder = (30, 30, ((10,10), (11,9), (11,10), (11,11), (12,9), (12,11), (13,10)))


    M, N, STARTING_LIVE_CELLS, ITERATIONS = *small_exploder, 0

    g = Game(M, N, STARTING_LIVE_CELLS)
    g.show()
```

Comment: If you want something to happen after a delay (like updating the state of the object on a `Canvas`, you can use the `after()` [universal widget method](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) to arrange for a function that does that to be called when the time is up. This function can also call `after()` itself and arrange for another call to itself to be made after another interval of time. That's how animation is often done with tkinter.

Comment: I modified your updated code to avoid the "garbage objects" issue, however the pattern stops changing after about 20 iterations as though it has reached a steady state. (I haven't make the effort to figure out if that's really the case as or not based on the rules.) If I let it continue to run, Aafter 110 iterations a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` occurs on the `tmp = deepcopy(cell)` line—which doesn't make sense as far as I can tell.

Comment: I have an idea what's wrong, but can spend any more time on it right now. Maybe tomorrow if you or someone else hasn't figured it out all ready...

Comment: Reconsider your approach. In `def update_canvas(...` you do `.create_rectangle(...`, instead of **update == change color** a rectangle. This results in an unlimited amout of canvas object and it's likely to eat all memory.

Comment: I would store all the rectangles in a list and then based on that list update each ones color instead of creating new ones. This should get rid of the slow down effect you are seeing from creating new rectangles ever cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got things figured-out and your script to work without crashing. The recursion problem I was encountering after fixed the garbage object issue was because the `mainloop()` was getting called over and over. It should only ever be called once in tkinter script.

This version avoids constantly creating more and more tkinter rectangles by "tagging" them all with the *same* tag value, which allows all of them to be deleted as a group with a single `Canvas.delete()` method call.

It would be more efficient to just modify the existing rectangles each iteration, but this version just deletes and recreates them all each iteration. To update them would require some way to reference them individually after they are created. If I feel motivated, and you're interested, I may update this answer later to this.

I've made numerous changes, but your core code is still there.

```
# Game of life
from random import randint
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
from enum import Enum
import tkinter as tk


class State(Enum):
    Dead = 0
    Alive = 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    @property
    def color(self):
        return 'blue' if self.value else 'red'


class Cell:
    def __init__(self, m, n, state):
        self.m = np.uint(m)
        self.n = np.uint(n)
        self.state = state

    def kill(self):
        self.state = State.Dead

    def birth(self):
        self.state = State.Alive

    def __str__(self):
        return '({},{}) {}'.format(self.m, self.n, self.state)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({},{}) {}'.format(self.m, self.n, self.state)


class Game:
    CELL_TAG = 'cells'

    def __init__(self, m, n, alive_cells = None):
        self.m = m
        self.n = n
        self.grid = np.ndarray((m,n), dtype = np.uint8)

        if alive_cells:
            self.cells = [Cell(i // n, i % n,
                State.Alive if (i // n, i % n) in alive_cells else State.Dead)
                    for i in range(m*n)]
        else:
            self.cells = [Cell(i / n, i % n, randint(0,1)) for i in range(m*n)]

        # GUI #
        self.top = tk.Tk()
        self.cell_size = 10000 // 400  # (self.m * self.n)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.top, bg="gray", height=self.m * self.cell_size,
                                                      width=self.n * self.cell_size)
        self.canvas.pack()

    def populate_grid(self):
        for cell in self.cells:
            self.grid[cell.m, cell.n] = cell.state.value

    def show(self, show_GUI = True, print_2_console = False):
        self.populate_grid()

        if print_2_console:
            print('#'*self.m*3)
            print(self.grid)
        if show_GUI:
            self.draw_canvas()
            self.top.mainloop()

    def iterate(self):
        '''
        Rules:
        (1) If cell has less than 2 neighbours, it dies
        (2) If cell has more than 3 neighbours, it dies
        (3) If cell has 2-3 neighbours, it survives
        (4) If cell has 3 neighbours, it rebirths
        '''
        new_cells = []
        for cell in self.cells:
            alive_neighbours = 0
            for i in range(cell.m - 1, cell.m + 2):
                for j in range(cell.n - 1, cell.n + 2):
                    if i == cell.m and j == cell.n:
                        continue
                    else:
                        try:
                            alive_neighbours += self.grid[i,j]
                        except IndexError:
                            pass

            tmp = deepcopy(cell)

            if alive_neighbours < 2 or alive_neighbours > 3:
                tmp.kill()
            elif alive_neighbours == 3:
                tmp.birth()
            else: # == 2
                pass

            new_cells.append(tmp)

        self.cells = new_cells
        self.populate_grid()
        self.draw_canvas()

    def draw_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.delete(self.CELL_TAG)  # Gets rid of any existing cell rects.

        for cell in self.cells:
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(
                cell.n*self.cell_size, cell.m*self.cell_size,
                (1+cell.n)*self.cell_size, (1+cell.m)*self.cell_size,
                fill=cell.state.color, tag=self.CELL_TAG)

        self.top.after(100, self.iterate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    glider = (20, 20, ((1,3), (2,3), (2,1), (3,2), (3,3)))
    small_exploder = (30, 30, ((10,10), (11,9), (11,10), (11,11), (12,9), (12,11), (13,10)))

    M, N, STARTING_LIVE_CELLS, ITERATIONS = *small_exploder, 0

    g = Game(M, N, STARTING_LIVE_CELLS)
    g.show()
```

Comment: CIsForCookies: Thanks. BTW, I have another working version that doesn't recreate all the canvas rectangles—instead it just modifies the existing ones each iteration. In that way it's similar to @Mike - SMT's answer, however one difference is that it doesn't require creating  an additional `self.canvas_rect_list` to keep track of them all, instead it just creates a unique `tag` for each one based on its cell index. LMK if you would like me to replace or add it to my current answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code to use a list to store each cell and then update the color. This can be done by using a class attribute list and tracking the index of each cell in `self.cells`.

This appears to fix the slow down issues. That said your updates will stop around 17 iterations on my end. It looks like your game of life rules cause it to stop on round 17 do to none of the cells fitting the rules to change at that point. The code continues to loop just no changes made after round 17.

I have added some comments where all the major changes were made to your code:

```
# Game of life
from random import randint
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
from enum import Enum
import tkinter as tk


class State(Enum):
    Dead    = 0
    Alive   = 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


class Cell:    
    def __init__(self, m, n, state):
        self.m = np.uint(m)
        self.n = np.uint(n)
        self.state = state

    def kill(self):
        self.state = State.Dead

    def birth(self):
        self.state = State.Alive

    def __str__(self):
        return '({},{}) {}'.format(self.m, self.n, self.state)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({},{}) {}'.format(self.m, self.n, self.state)

# made the class inherit from Tk to make it easier to manage.
class Game(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, m, n, alive_cells=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.m = m
        self.n = n
        self.grid = np.ndarray((m, n), dtype = np.uint8)
        self.first = False # This variable is used to check if we need to draw or update rectangles.
        self.canvas_rect_list = [] # This list is used to track the list.
        if alive_cells:
            self.cells = [Cell(i // n,i % n, State.Alive if (i // n, i % n) in alive_cells else State.Dead) for i in range(m * n)]
        else:
            self.cells = [Cell(i / n, i % n, randint(0, 1)) for i in range(m * n)]
        self.cell_size = 10000 // 400 #(self.m * self.n)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="gray", height=self.m * self.cell_size, width=self.n * self.cell_size)
        self.show()

    def populate_grid(self):
        for cell in self.cells:
            self.grid[cell.m, cell.n] = cell.state.value

    def show(self, show_GUI=True, print_2_console=False):
        self.populate_grid()
        if print_2_console:
            print('#' * self.m * 3)
            print(self.grid)

        # Added this to check if we need to draw or update rectangles.
        if self.first == False:
            self.draw_canvas()
        else:
            self.update_canvas()

    def iterate(self):
        new_cells = []
        for cell in self.cells:
            alive_neighbours = 0
            for i in range(cell.m - 1, cell.m + 2):
                for j in range(cell.n - 1, cell.n + 2):
                    if i == cell.m and j == cell.n:
                        continue
                    else:
                        try:
                            alive_neighbours += self.grid[i, j]
                        except IndexError:
                            pass

            tmp = deepcopy(cell)
            if alive_neighbours < 2 or alive_neighbours > 3:
                tmp.kill()
            elif alive_neighbours == 3:
                tmp.birth()
            else: # == 2
                pass 

            new_cells.append(tmp)
        self.cells = new_cells
        self.show()

    def draw_canvas(self):    
        for cell in self.cells:
            if cell.state == State.Alive:
                color = 'blue'
            else:
                color = 'red'
            # Add each rectangle to a list.
            self.canvas_rect_list.append(self.canvas.create_rectangle(cell.n * self.cell_size, cell.m * self.cell_size, (1+cell.n) * self.cell_size, (1+cell.m) * self.cell_size, fill=color))

        # sets first to True after first use of draw so we do not create new rectangles later.
        self.first = True
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.update_canvas()

    def update_canvas(self): 
        for ndex, cell in enumerate(self.cells):
            if cell.state == State.Alive:
                color = 'blue'
            else:
                color = 'red'
            # Configure each item in list baste of cell state and index.
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_rect_list[ndex], fill=color)
        self.after(500, self.iterate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Change your glider and small_exploder variables to the
    # commented out ones below for an interesting pattern
    # That ends with a rotating 3 block line.
    # glider = (20, 17, ((1,3), (2,3), (2,1), (3,2), (3,3)))
    # small_exploder = (32, 30, ((12,10), (11,9), (11,10), (11,11), (12,9), (12,11), (14,10)))
    glider = (20, 17, ((1,3), (2,3), (2,1), (3,2), (3,3)))
    small_exploder = (32, 30, ((12,10), (11,9), (11,10), (11,11), (12,9), (12,11), (14,10)))
    M, N, STARTING_LIVE_CELLS, ITERATIONS = * small_exploder, 0
    g = Game(M, N, STARTING_LIVE_CELLS)
    g.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you've haven't expressed any interesting in seeing this version, I'm going to post it anyway because I think it might be of interest to others if not you—and because I've put a fair amount of time <del>playing with</del> working on it to improve and otherwise optimize it.

It keeps track of the `Canvas` rectangles created by adding an `id` attribute to the `Cell` class instances that to store the Canvas object id returned from `create_rectangle()` method—instead of a separate `canvas_rect_list`. This allows it to avoid recreating them every iteration.

In addition, the `iterate()` method no longer makes `deepcopy`s of each existing `Cell` in the process of creating a new list of them. It instead just updates the existing instances. This works because the way the rules are implement and they only reference the current values in the separate `grid` array which at that point hasn't yet been updated.

Speaking of which, I also made the use of the `numpy` library optional and use a dictionary in placed. The lines affected with that change all start with `#xnp`. This makes it runnable without installing any additional modules—but the code for using `numpy` is still there, if you really want to use it for some reason. (I personally don't think there much of an advantage in using it).

The result of all this is something that runs very fast and the code is very modular now. I've experimentally reduced the delay between iterations down to 16 msecs successfully and it really seemed to fly along...

```
# Conway's Game of life
from random import randint
from enum import IntEnum
#xnp  import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

DELAY = 100  # Msecs between iterations.

class State(IntEnum): Dead = False; Alive = True

class Cell:
    __slots__ = "m", "n", "state", "id"

    def __init__(self, m, n, state):
#xnp     self.m, self.n, self.state = np.uint(m), np.uint(n), state
        self.m, self.n, self.state = m, n, state
        self.id = None

    def get_posn(self):
        return self.m, self.n  # (Must) return a tuple.

    def kill(self):
        self.state = State.Dead

    def birth(self):
        self.state = State.Alive

    def __str__(self):
        return '({},{}) {}'.format(self.m, self.n, self.state)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({},{}) {}'.format(self.m, self.n, self.state)


class CanvasFrame(tk.Frame):
    COLORMAP = {State.Dead: 'red', State.Alive: 'blue'}

    def __init__(self, parent, m, n, cell_size, cells):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="gray", height=m*cell_size, width=n*cell_size)
        self.canvas.pack()

        COLORMAP = self.COLORMAP
        create_rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle
        for cell in cells:
            cell.id = create_rectangle(cell.n * cell_size, cell.m * cell_size,
                                       (cell.n+1) * cell_size, (cell.m+1) * cell_size,
                                       fill=COLORMAP[cell.state])

    def update_canvas(self, cells):
        COLORMAP = self.COLORMAP
        itemconfig = self.canvas.itemconfig
        for cell in cells:
            itemconfig(cell.id, fill=COLORMAP[cell.state])


class Game:

    def __init__(self, m, n, seed=None):
        self.m, self.n = m, n
        self.cell_size = 10000 // 400  # (self.m * self.n)
#xnp     self.grid = np.ndarray((m, n), dtype=np.uint8)
        self.grid = {}  # Use a dictionary instead of ndarray.

        states = tuple(s for s in State)  # Local var for faster access.
        statefunc = ((lambda q, r: states[(q, r) in seed]) if seed else
                     (lambda q, r: states[randint(0, 1)]))
        self.cells = [Cell(q, r, statefunc(q, r))
                        for q, r in (divmod(i, n) for i in range(m*n))]
        self.populate_grid()

    def populate_grid(self):
#xnp     for cell in self.cells:
#xnp         self.grid[cell.m, cell.n] = cell.state.value
        self.grid = {cell.get_posn(): cell.state.value for cell in self.cells}

    def show(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.container = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.canvasframe = CanvasFrame(self.container, self.m, self.n, self.cell_size, self.cells)
        self.canvasframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")  # Each in same location.

        self.container.after(500, self.tick)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def tick(self):
        """ Transition to next generation. """
        self.iterate()  # Update cells and grid.
        self.canvasframe.update_canvas(self.cells)
        self.container.after(DELAY, self.tick)

    def iterate(self):
        """
        Rules:
        (1) If cell has less than 2 neighbours, it dies
        (2) If cell has more than 3 neighbours, it dies
        (3) If cell has 2-3 neighbours, it survives
        (4) If cell has 3 neighbours, it rebirths
        """
        deltas = ((-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
                  ( 0, -1),          ( 0, 1),
                  ( 1, -1), ( 1, 0), ( 1, 1))

        for cell in self.cells:
            alive_neighbours = 0
            m, n = cell.m, cell.n
            for i, j in ((m+dm, n+dn) for dm, dn in deltas):
                try:
                    alive_neighbours += self.grid[i, j]
                # Exception depends on whether np is being used or not.
                except (KeyError, IndexError):
                    pass

            if alive_neighbours < 2 or alive_neighbours > 3:  # Death?
                cell.state = State.Dead
            elif alive_neighbours == 3:  # Birth?
                cell.state = State.Alive

        self.populate_grid()  # Update.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    glider = (20, 20, ((1,3), (2,3), (2,1), (3,2), (3,3)))
    small_exploder = (30, 30, ((10,10), (11,9), (11,10), (11,11), (12,9), (12,11), (13,10)))
    random_pattern = (30, 30, None)
# @Mike - SMT version that runs longer.
    small_exploder = (32, 30, ((12,10), (11,9), (11,10), (11,11), (12,9), (12,11), (14,10)))

#    g = Game(*small_exploder)
    g = Game(*random_pattern)
    g.show()
```

Here's it running from a random starting point:

[image: Screenshot of it running]